# Validating multiple drop downs

Tags: javascript, validation

thisI have four drop downs on my web email form as below

```
<select  name="newstaff"  class="formStyle" style="width:335px;" >
<option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
---- other options ---
<select name="allstaff"  class="formStyle" style="width:335px;" >
<option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
 ---- other options ---
<select  name="learning"  class="formStyle" style="width:400px;" >
<option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
---- other options ---
<select  name="leaders"  class="formStyle" style="width:335px;" >
<option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
---- other options ---
```

How would I write a validation function that would bring up an alert if a user tried to submit this form without selecting at least one of the other options from at least one drop down "N/A

thanks

**Edit:**

Code used to validate form:

```
function validateForm(objForm)
{
    var returnStatus = 1;

    if (objForm.newstaff.selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert("please make a selection!");
        returnStatus = 0;
    };
    if (returnStatus) {
        objForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The difference here getting the array of elements with the tag name of `select`.

```
validateForm = function(objForm) {
    var i = 0,
        valid = false,
        elements = objForm.getElementsByTagName("select");

    for ( ; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].selectedIndex) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid === true) {
        objForm.submit();
    } else {
        alert ("Please make a selection!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `elements[i].selectedIndex > 0` check is not needed.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the clarification - I updated the answer.

Comment: validateForm = function(objForm) how do I call the function

Comment: `validateForm(formVariable)` - just like normal. I prefer this syntax as being a little easier to read.

Comment: Hi Could I place this function in an external script without making any changes?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of - yes.

Comment: @Kaf. I appreciate your comments. See https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/ for why I like to first define the iterator variable - just style :).

Comment: This works great but the validation occurs on page load, I would like it to validate last after all other fields have been validated. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: It's all a matter of when you call it. If you want to open up a new question, post the link here, and I'll take a look. Oh, and make sure to check this as an answer if it answered your original question!